# k-fold cross validation for GLMM S4 class model object

Tags: r, lme4, r-s4

I have a GLMM object fit using the `glmer` function in `R` and want to perform k-fold cross validation.  For simple GLMs I have used the `CVbinary` function from the `DAAG` pkg as seen below.

```
> SimpleGLM <- glm(Res ~ Var1 + Var2, data = Data, family=binomial)
> CVbinary(SimpleGLM,  nfolds=10, print.details=TRUE)

Fold:  3 2 4 1 7 10 6 9 5 8
Internal estimate of accuracy = 0.828
Cross-validation estimate of accuracy = 0.827
```

However, when a random term for IndID is added to the model an error (below) results from the S4 class of a model fit with `glmer`.

```
GLMMod <- glmer(Res ~ Var1 + Var2 + (1|IndID), data = Data, family=binomial)
> CVbinary(GLMMod ,  nfolds=10, print.details=TRUE)

Error in obj$data : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

I have been looking online and have been unable to find a function similar to `CVbinary` that works with S4 objects, but wanted to double check here before I code it manually.

In short, (assuming I am correctly interpreting the `R` error) is there a function that performs k-fold cross validation on S4 objects?

Comment: note that this is cross-posted on the r-sig-mixed-models mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2013q4/021472.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be well-advised to examine the statistical assumptions underlying the question. When the experts approach this for assessment of p-values for individual factors, they emphasize the need to do bootstrapping with proper attention to the study design implied by the random factor specification. See the ["draft" GLMM FAQ](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq). (Credit to @BenBolker for authorship and maintenance of that resource. It has expanded greatly in the last year and now even has some kewl graphics. It's on its way to becoming a book chapter.) The author of DAAG has also published DAAGxtras which has a compareModels function which you could set up after using the newly introduced predict methods in pkg:lme4

There's also the resource of the mixed-models-in-R Archive: http://markmail.org/search/?q=+list%3Aorg.r-project.r-sig-mixed-models+cross-validation

Comment: note development/current version of GLMM faq has [moved](https://rawgit.com/bbolker/mixedmodels-misc/master/glmmFAQ.html)

Comment: I do not understand why this question is marked as answered if no function has been yet proposed.