# k-fold cross validation of GLMM in R

Tags: r, package

Is there any R package to perform k-fold cross validation of GLMM?
I know with DAAG package (and "cv.binary()" function) it is possible to perform k-fold cross validation, but for GLM. With GLMM, this error appears:

```
Error in obj$data : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Does anyone know how to conduct these analyses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684617/k-fold-cross-validation-for-glmm-s4-class-model-object

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this package, which includes functionality for cross-validation of GLMMs (although it only appears to support a couple of family link functions). https://github.com/LudvigOlsen/cvms

But I would also keep in mind that there is a body of literature discussing the assumptions of cross-validation for GLMM (e.g. see [Colby and Blair (2013)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10928-013-9313-5) and [Fang (2011)](http://www.jds-online.com/file_download/278/JDS-652a.pdf), which I read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18971/cross-validation-for-mixed-models) when looking into a related question.